# Edittext not displaying data type in custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher, listview-adapter

I have a custom listview with edittext. I am using textwatcher and trying to add new row when texted type in edittext is greater then zero.

But whatever i type it doesn't show in my edittext.

[image]

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        final int c = position;
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        Button delbtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delbutn);
    txtTitle.setText(itemname.get(position));
     edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
             String txt = edittext.getText().toString();
             if(txt.length()>0)
             {
                 if(!txt.equals("0"))
                 {
                     Log.e("test", txt);
                MainActivity.itemname.add("new"); 
                // itemname.add("new");
                    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // MainActivity.adapter.insert("", 0);

                 }

             } 
            }

            @Override    
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int count, int after) 
            {

            }

            @Override    
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int before, int count) {

            }
           });
        return rowView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
```

use this

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agent_details_list, parent, false);
```